# Taskbar programming

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface

I'm planning to program simple taskbar manager for Linux like Tint2 but with my own ideas implemented. It'll be some kind of mix between unity and tint.

I have experience in OpenGL, C++, Python...

- Now I'm wondering what do I have to know to create such taskbar?
- How are things like this done? Which libraries should I use?
- What do I have to do if I want to do this with OpenGl, how hard is it?
- Do I need to program for specific window manager (I'm using OpenBox)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should have an understanding of how X and window managers work. You may want to learn about startup notification as well.
2. This is too open-ended to answer.
3. ... Eleventy-seven?
4. No. But you should understand ICCCM and EWMH so you can play nice with them.